# How to show $L = \{a^n b^m c^p: n\neq m\} \cup \{a^n b^m c^p: m\neq p\}$ is ambiguous?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

I'm recently familiar with this site and prefer to ask a very hard problem :)

How can we prove that the following language is inherently ambiguous?

> $$L = \{a^n b^m c^p: n\neq m\} \cup \{a^n b^m c^p: m\neq p\}$$

this is an example in my note without a proof.

Comment: By the way, if you want to ask a question in the future then you should show any work you've done to answer it.

Comment: I know this is very difficult. I wait for one expert.

Comment: I can offer a simplification to the problem. It is enough to show that $\{a^n b^m c^p : (n\neq m) \land (m\neq p)\}$, which is a subset of the requested language, is inherently ambiguous.